# How to debug a NullPointerException in Processing?

Tags: processing

I am making an animation in Processing it is a simulation of a ball going up and coming down, I have an error saying 'NullPointerException' it keeps appearing I will give the code and show the error place:

```java
Obj[] objs = new Obj[100];

void setup(){
  size(1000, 1000);
}

void draw(){
  background(250);
  for(int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++){
    objs[i].render();
    objs[i].up();
    objs[i].run();
  }
}

the error is at objs[i].render();
```

here is the code for Obj:

```java
  class Obj{
  float x;
  float y;
  float speed;
  float pspeed;
  float velocity;
  void render(){
    fill(0);
    ellipse(x, y, 5, 5);
  }
  void up(){
    x = random(-1000, 1000);
    y = y-1010;
  }
  void run(){
    speed = random(4, 6);
    pspeed = speed;
    velocity = 0.05; 
    while(y<random(700, 1100)){
      y=y-speed;
      speed=speed-velocity;
    }

    while(y>0){
      y=y+pspeed;
      pspeed = pspeed - velocity;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not showing the context of the call to draw. I would guess that the reason of the NPE is that you are not initializing the elements of objs

Answer (score 0):

This line creates an array that can hold 100 instances of `Obj`:

```java
Obj[] objs = new Obj[100];
```

But it doesn't actually create any instances. In other words, your array contains 100 `null` values.

Then you're looping through those `null` values and trying to call functions on them, which is what's causing your error.

To fix the problem, you probably just want to fill your array up with instances:

```java
void setup(){
  size(1000, 1000);

  for(int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++){
    objs[i] = new Obj();
  }
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on arrays in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arrays).